# jQuery Fading Issue

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a minimal-style validation response for my login box. There's not a lot of space, so I change "Login" to say "Invalid Login. Forgot Password?" in a nice fading animation. I had it working previously when I merely inserted "Invalid" before "Login" rather than fading out then in the entire span.

When it comes to my code, the former span doesn't disappear and the latter span just shows up below, as if I am doing .show(). Also, no fading whatsoever occurs, which is odd.

Here's my markup:

```
<span id="oldLoginProblem"><h3>Login</h3></span>
<span id="newLoginProblem" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"><h3>Invalid Login &#183; <a href='recover'>Forgot Password?</a></h3></span>
```

Here's the jQuery (this runs on validation error):

```
if(data == "Invalid")
            {
                $('#oldLoginProblem').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $('#newLoginProblem').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                        $('#newLoginProblem').fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                });
            }
```

Any help?

Comment: Why not just fade out the error message, change the text with `.html()`, restyle it with `.css()`, and fade it back in? It'll save you a few lines of HTML and JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in other answers, you cannot have a block element in an inline element (`h3` in a `span`).

If you change your spans to `inline-block`, it works, but I don't know if that has other consequences with regard to your layout.

```
span {
     display: inline-block;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your fading problem is probably caused by the fact that `span` is an **inline** element:

http://jsfiddle.net/proudlygeek/AUC5v/

### Update

Here's a snippet containing the *fading effect* you want:

```
$('#loginProblem').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).html("<h3>Invalid Login &#183; <a href='recover'>Forgot Password?</a></h3>");
    $(this).css({
        'color': 'red',
        'font-weight': 'bold'
    });
    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**See** it in action on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/proudlygeek/AUC5v/1/)

Comment: I'm using that exact code and the elements still appear and disappear as if I am using show/hide rather than fades.

Comment: @Sennheiser That's strange indeed. Have you seen the example i've created on jsFiddle? I can see the fading transition on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an issue with calling `.fadeOut()` with an `<h3/>` element inside a `<span/>` (which is invalid markup as you can not have a block level element inside of an inline element)

With that being said you can get the `fadeOut()` effect to work by using `.children()`

```
$('#oldLoginProblem').children().fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#newLoginProblem').children().fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#newLoginProblem').children().fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

**[Code Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/eNdGz/)**

Another option would be to simply adjust your markup to be valid and the fadeOut will work correctly.

```
<h3 id="oldLoginProblem"><span>Login</span></h3>
<h3 id="newLoginProblem"><span  style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">Invalid Login &#183; <a href='recover'>Forgot Password?</a></span></h3>
```

**[Code Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/eNdGz/1/)**